# Changing the primary key on a referenced table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I would like to know if there is an "easy" way of changing the primary key that is an UUID of 36 characters for an autoincrement column. The problem is that this table is referenced by at least another 25 tables (around 50 columns)

I'm using InnoDB and Foreign Key Constraints.

Comment: I like the fact is isn't easy to change this, because it serves as a warning about why these decisions should not be taken lightly.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem too hard:

1. Make sure all your foreign key constraints are defined as `ON UPDATE CASCADE` (so when you update the key value, the children's fks are updated too)
2. Update each value with an integer (but still text, of course)
3. `ALTER TABLE my_table my_id_column INT AUTO_INCREMENT`

How you chose the new integer value from the key is up to you. Perhaps just using this simple query to number them from 1 up in the order specified:

```
set @i:=0;
update my_table set
my_id_column = (@i := @i + 1)
order by some_ordering_column;
```

FYI, I just tested all the code here and it works.

Comment: The ability to add an `AUTO_INCREMENT` to a MySQL table via `ALTER TABLE` was a recent addition (v5.5+) IIRC

Comment: Thank you very much Bohemian, I was thinking to create an extra column just to fill all the ids with a number, and then changing the primary key, but I think your solution is better, thanks.

Comment: it did not worked for me until I deleted the foreign key constraint. Are you sure you are using InnoDB with FK constraints?